# Ejecting a hidden volume

Tags: macos, hidden-fields, volumes

I was having a problem with the script that creates my installer for macosx not working and I discovered it was because it was creating a folder called /Volumes/myinstaller 1 instead of /Volumes/myinstaller.  While investigating this issue I found that I have a hidden volume called /Volumes/myinstaller with all the relevant files inside but I cannot rmdir the directory because it contains many layers of files.  Is there someway to eject a hidden volume through the terminal or to see the hidden volume in the finder?

Comment: does the command `umount /Volumes/myinstaller\ 1` works (maybe with sudo) ?

Comment: It says its not currently mounted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh heh rm -r worked.  Oh well duh.

Answer (score 2):

In general, to dismount volumes, hidden or otherwise, you want to use `diskutil unmount` (or `hdiutil detach`) and not `umount`, thanks to OSX's `diskarbitrationd`:

```
$ sudo umount /Volumes/NAME/
Password:
umount: unmount(/Volumes/NAME): Resource busy
$ diskutil unmount /Volumes/NAME/
Volume NAME  on disk3s1 unmounted
```

It is also possible to use diskutil to return information about mounted volumes in a structured way (a plist) for scripting.  See the man pages for diskutil and hdiutil for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, rm worked here to. Here is the command siquence I used.

cd /volumes && sudo rm -rf [name of invisible volume]

worked like a charm here.